# Flutter AnimatedBuilder causing lag

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have this animation which was working smoothly using an AnimationController, but once I tried to animate the color of a CircleAvatar using AnimattedBuilder the whole animation got very laggy. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
// Init:
void initState() {
  _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: _animationDuration,
    vsync: this,
  );

  _circleAvatarAnimation = Tween<Color>(
    begin: const Color(0xFFEFEDE1),
    end: const Color(0xFF333333)
  ).animate(_controller);

  super.initState();
}

// Animation:
AnimatedBuilder(
  animation: _circleAvatarAnimation,
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) => CircleAvatar(
    radius: 12,
    backgroundColor: _circleAvatarAnimation.value,
    child: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.feather, size: 17, color: _labelColor)
  ),
),

// Animation Trigger:
GestureDetector(
  onPanUpdate: (dragDetails) {
    if (dragDetails.delta.dx > 0) {
      _controller.forward();

      setState(() {
        selectedGuitar = 1;
        _containerColors = [
          const Color(0xFF252525),
          const Color(0xFF6E6E6E)
        ];
        _labelColor = const Color(0xFFEFEDE1);
      });
  
    } else if (dragDetails.delta.dx < 0) {
      _controller.reverse();

      setState(() {
        selectedGuitar = 0;
        _containerColors = [
          const Color(0xFFEFEDE1),
          const Color(0xFFCECECE),
        ];
        _labelColor = const Color(0xFF333333);
      });
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Have you tried building the project with `flutter build --release`?

Comment: I get an error: `Could not find an option named "release".`

Answer (score 1):

The laggy animation issue may occur because you are triggering the animation inside the GestureDetector's onPanUpdate callback, which can lead to multiple rapid changes to the animation and cause performance problems.

Comment: I actually tried using a bool variable to only have it be triggered once and it was still lagging. The fix to the issue was to use a `ColorTween` rather than a `Tween<Color>`